# python http error 400

Tags: python, http

i am trying to send http request but i always get http error 400

what should I do?

this is the code:

```
def login(params):
    url = "https://cps-inbararan.c9users.io/DBI/listener.php?func_name=%s&params=%s"%("exists_user",json.dumps(params))
    ans = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
    return ans.split("::")[0]
```

and this is the error

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
File "UMC_Handler.py", line 22, in <module>
  ans = uf.login(params)
File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/UMC_func.py", line 60, in login
  ans = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
  return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 410, in open
  response = meth(req, response)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 523, in http_response
  'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 448, in error
  return self._call_chain(*args)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
  result = func(*args)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 531, in http_error_default
  raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad request
```

Comment: did you try that request in a normal browser without url lib?

Comment: Look at the value you are generating for `url`.

Comment: Well then your url is wrong. I just tried to paste it into my browser and its not a valid page

Comment: the `url` without get parameters works, meaning I get `3100 Missing GET parameter::params`, so figure out what valid `params` to pass to that url and it should work

Comment: the url dont work all the time because its my c9 server. and i think that the the json do all the problems, but i dont know why